# Why the droid keep moving through the door and other objects even if i add a box collider to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Droid]

The droid have a box collider also the door have a box collider.
But when i move the character(FPSController/FirstPersoncharacter) the player the character stop can't move through the door but the droid can.

I tried to turn off/on the Is Trigger property on the droid box collider but it didn't change.

[image: Droid]

I want the droid to act like the player when colliding with other objects like the droid is part of the player.

The only code i'm using is attached to the FirstPersonCharacter:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;

    private float distance;
    private Camera cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cam.transform.position, droid.transform.position);
        droid.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            droid.SetActive(!droid.activeInHierarchy);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add a Rigidbody component to the droid to the NAVI or to the Droid_Player but it didn't solve it. I don't have any other code that handle collidings.

UPDATE to what i tried and did so far:

From the NAVI (Droid) i removed the box collider component and added two things:

1. Character Controller component
2. Control script (This script is coming with the NAVI(Droid))

This is the Control script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float rotationDamping = 20f;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public int gravity = 0;
    public Animator animator;

    float verticalVel;  // Used for continuing momentum while in air    
    CharacterController controller;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = (CharacterController)GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController));
    }

    float UpdateMovement()
    {
        // Movement
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 inputVec = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        inputVec *= speed;

        controller.Move((inputVec + Vector3.up * -gravity + new Vector3(0, verticalVel, 0)) * Time.deltaTime);

        // Rotation
        if (inputVec != Vector3.zero)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, 
                                                  Quaternion.LookRotation(inputVec), 
                                                  Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);

        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    void AnimationControl ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("s") || Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("w")) 
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Moving" , true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Moving" , false);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("space")) 
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Angry" , true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Angry" , false);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("mouse 0")) 
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Scared" , true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool ("Scared" , false);
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {   
        UpdateMovement();
        AnimationControl();


        if ( controller.isGrounded )
            verticalVel = 0f;// Remove any persistent velocity after landing
    }
}
```

Now when i move the character close to a door or wall also the NAVI(Droid) stop and is not moving through the door or wall and this is fine. But now i have another problem. If i will keep moving to the door or wall it looks like the character is moving over/on the NAVI Droid.

The Navi droid is not changing position.

In this screenshot is how it looks like when i moved close to the door the collider on the door and the NAVI Droid are working and the navi droid can't move through the door:

[image: Navi droid]

In this screenshot you can see what is happened when i kept moving the character to the door. On the top screen view the NAVI droid is in the same position but on the Game View on the bottom it seems like the character is moving over/on the NAVI droid.

[image: Navi droid]

And if i will keep moving to the door the character will not move but the droid looks like pushed back or the character will keep moving over the droid.

This is a short video clip i recorded showing the problem.

The problem start at second 20:

[Collider problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9T0Ft7nu1k&feature=youtu.be)

I tried to add box collider to the droid tried rigidbody nothing worked only this script and component but now i have this problem in the video.

Comment: How is the droid moved? It looks like it is a child of your player, that might effect things. (`isTrigger` by the way, when true, makes the collider non-solid, representing things like motion sensor *trigger* volumes).

Comment: @Draco18s right the droid is moving only by being child of the FirstPaersonCharacter that have a camera attached so this way i can move the droid with the player.

Comment: @Draco18s i have just updated here my question with the Control script that i attached to the NAVI Droid this script is coming in the original with the NAVI Droid. And also the Character Controller i added to the NAVI Droid. With this component and script and when the NAVI Droid is child of the FirstPersonCharacter the colliders are working also for the NAVI Droid but as i mentioned in the Update in my question i have now another problem with the NAVI Droid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your droid probably needs a RigidBody component.

If that doesn't solve it, you should add some relevant code snippets to your question to show how/where you've tried to detect and handle collisions.

Comment: I don't have any code that handle collisions. And i tried to add a Rigidbody component to both NAVI and then to Droid_Player but it didn't solve it.